# $\int_0^x f(t) dt = x + \int_0^1 f(t) dt$ from Thomas' Calculus 14th Edition.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**The Problem**:
If
$$
\int_0^x f(t) dt=x+\int_0^1 f(t)dt \tag{1}
$$
Find the value of $f(1)$.

The answer to this problem is stated $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. I'm neither able to reach that nor find another one which holds $(1)$ true.

**My Attempt 1:**
Let
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt
$$
then, per Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have
$$
F'(x)=f(x)
$$
Since
$$
F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t) dt=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+\int_0^1 f(t)dt\right)=1 \\
\therefore F'(x)=f(x)=1 \implies \boxed{f(1)=1}
$$

But this is apparently wrong. If I take $f(x)=1$, $(1)$ doesn't hold.

Am I doing something wrong or is the problem statement wrong? Do functions exist that satisfy $(1)$?

**Further research:**
The assertion $(1)$ fails for $x=1$. So I assume the assertion is not valid for $x=1$ and valid everywhere else. Then
$$
F(0)=\int_0^0f(t)dt=0+\int_0^1f(t)dt
$$

Note that $F(0)=0$. Therefore
$$
\int_0^1f(t)dt=0
$$

Finally arriving at
$$
\int_0^x f(t)dt=x
$$

which, again, makes no sense because for $x=1$
$$
\int_0^1 f(t)dt=1
$$

Comment: you are correct (assuming that $f$ is continuous).

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm correct as in $\displaystyle f(x)=1$ or "The problem statement is wrong?

Comment: that $f(x)=1$ ${}{}{}{$

Comment: @ArcticChar with $f(x)=1$, the problem assertion does not hold.

Comment: For which $x$ is $(1)$ supposed to hold? Because when you plug in $x = 1$ you get a contradiction...

Comment: The answer says $f(1) =1/2$, which is wrong. The correct one is $f(1)=1$. (But probably the the above comment is much better - your question is broken)

Comment: as @user23571113 says, there's no $f$ defined on the real number set satisfying (1) because x=1 is obviously a contradiction; By applying FTC you get a necessary condition of (1) but not a sufficient one to guarantee (1) holds.

Comment: The question never says that $f$ needs to be continuous. But I still think it's a weird question.

Comment: It is strange that nothing is stated about $f$: its domain, its codomain, its regularity (at least integrable to give sense to the integrals)! Looks like a problem taken from Instagram.

Comment: @Dunkelheit the problem is from Thomas Calculus 14th edition.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa Where exactly did you find the problem? On which page?

Comment: If (1) is satisfied for all $x\neq 1$, taking $x\to 1$ will give (1) for $x=1$, which is again absurd.

Comment: @Azlif Chapter 5, Page 288, Exercise 69.

Comment: I think the lower limit of the second integral is supposed to be $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in $x=1$ into your equation (1), you'll get
$$F(1) = 1 + F(1)$$

So the problem is ill-posed, or we can stretch it and assume that it's not a proper integral and $F(1)=\pm\infty$.

If you differenciate (1) however, you'll get $$F'(x) = f(x) = 1 = \frac d{dx}(x+F(1))$$ so it won't even work for improper integrals.

Maybe it's just a typo like the problem is supposed to be
$$\int_0^x f(t) dt = x - \int_0^1 f(t) dt$$

Comment: Even with hypothetical typos, differentiating is not allowed because the fundamental theorem of calculus requires $f$ to be at least continuous: hence, without any regularity hypothesis on $f$, it is not true that $F'=f$.